# Extract logindate from user object and populate a new field in a custom object via batch apex

Tags: apex, datetime, date

I would like to apologise if any spelling mistakes , in currently posting this on an iPhone whilst I commute home

I found a link online which I think meets my requirements

As we are all aware lastlogin date on user object is accessible via formulas and triggers.
However I been told it can be accessed via visual force pages and a batch apex. I don't want to go down the route of visual force so in looking at batch apex.

I want to get the last login date from the user object an populate anther field in a custom object. The field I would like to populate is abc_test, and object is called mason

I have found the following trigger but I don't no why field names I need to change to meet my critters, and whether this trigger should be put in my custom object or user object

I am aware that this needs to be scheduled job aswell

Looking forward to your help 
D

```
public void ResetlastLogin_Update(List<User> oldUsers, List<User> newUsers) {

System.debug('ResetlastLogin_Update: entering trigger');

List<Id> idsToUpdate = new List<Id>();

for (integer i=0; i<newUsers.size(); i++) {
 User newVals = newUsers[i];
  User oldVals = oldUsers[i];

 if (newVals.lastlogindate != oldVals.lastlogindate__c) {
      idsToUpdate.add(newVals.Id);
 }
}
System.debug('Ids to Update: ' + idsToUpdate.size());

if (idsToUpdate.size() > 0) {

List<User> usersToUpdate = [SELECT Id, lastlogindate, lastlogindate__c FROM User WHERE Id  IN :idsToUpdate];
for (User u : usersToUpdate) {

 if (u.lastlogindate__c == NULL ) {

 u.lastlogindate__c = u.lastlogindate ;
 }
}
update usersToUpdate;

}

System.debug('ResetlastLogin_Update_Update: exiting trigger');
}
```

Comment: Are you having any issues with this? Does it work?

Comment: Ericssh - I haven't tested it, but I would assume I would need to change field names to reference the field I want to populate and in what object. However I am unsure what fields I would need to change.

Comment: You're going to have to put in your custom object, and mess around with it, but it appears this would be a good start

Comment: Where would I reference my custom object though ?  If I'm reading the above correctly the trigger is extracting the logins I'd and date , and then populating another field with that date , but what forks is he populating ?

Answer (score 1):

You have all the data you need, after you get the data out of the `User` object you will need to push it over to your custom object..

```
for(customObject c :[Select something FROM customObject WHERE CreatedById(maybe?) In :idsToUpdate]){
c.somethingToUpdate = usersToUpdate.get(c.somethingToUpdate).LastLoginDate;}
```

This is super rough, and should be taken with a grain of salt so don't copy and paste this and expect it to work.  Try something and come back with some more info